# Which data store is best for my scenario

Tags: database, database-design, database-performance, in-memory-database, nosql

I'm working on an application that involves very high execution of update / select queries in the database.

I have a base table (A) which will have about 500 records for an entity for a day. And for every user in the system, a variation of this entity is created based on some of the preferences of the user and they are stored in another table (B). This is done by a cron job that runs at midnight everyday.

So if there are 10,000 users and 500 records in table A, there will be 5M records in table B for that day. I always keep data for one day in these tables and at midnight I archive historical data to HBase. This setup is working fine and I'm having no performance issues so far.

There has been some change in the business requirements lately and now some attributes in base table A ( for 15 - 20 records) will change every 20 seconds and based on that I have to recalculate some values for all of those variation records in table B for all users. Even though only 20 master records change, I need to do recalculation and update 200,000 user records which takes more than 20 seconds and by then the next update occurs eventually resulting in all Select queries getting queued up. I'm getting about 3 get request / 5 seconds from online users which results in 6-9 Select queries. To respond to an api request, I always use the fields in table B.

I can buy more processing power and solve this situation but I'm interested in having a properly scaled system which can handle even a million users.

Can anybody here suggest a better alternative? Does nosql + relational database help me here ? Are there any platforms / datastores which will let me update data frequently without locking and at the same time give me the flexibility of running select queries on various fields in an entity ?

Cheers
Jugs

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at an in memory DBMS  that fully implements MVCC, to eliminate blocking issues. If your application is currently using SQL, then there's no reason to move away from that to nosql. The performance requirements you describe can certainly be met by an in memory SQL-capable DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your saying you are updating 200K records for every 20 sec. Then like in 10min you will update almost all of your data. In that case why are you writing those state to database if that is so frequently updated. I don't know anything about your requirements but why don't you just calculate it on demand using data from table A?